# Find all polynomials that satisfy a functional equation

Tags: polynomials, functional-equations

I need help with this problem if anyone can contribute to solving this I would much appreciate it:

> Find all polynomials $P$ that satisfy $P(1)=210$
> and for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$: $$(x+10)P(2x)=(8x-32)P(x+6).$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What have you tried?

Comment: Plug in $x = \frac{1}{2}$, what do you get?

Comment: Also try $x= -5$

Comment: Ok thank you all for your contribution

Answer (score 1):

$$P(x) = c (-8 + x) (-4 + x) (4 + x)$$

Comment: My solution is right. Who down voted it?

Comment: I didn't down vote it

Comment: upvote if you find it useful

Comment: at  least will even out

Comment: True i forgot to sum +6 f(x-6), now it is updated

Comment: the other answer is  incomplete

Answer (score 1):

**small hint**

With $ x=-10 $, we get
$$P(-10+6)=P(-4)=0$$
and for $ x=4 $, it gives
$$P(8)=0$$

thus

$$P(x)=(x-8)(x+4)R(x)$$
with
$$R(1)=\frac{210}{-35}=-6$$

Comment: Subbing $x=2$ gives yet another root.

Comment: Thank you very much